# Restrict filesystem access to wsgi daemon users

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I configured 2 mod_wsgi daemons with 2 different os users and groups. Apache will properly spawn a  daemon for each user:

```
# ps -eF
root     10188     1  0  4586  6204   0 09:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
501      10190 10188  0 50531 13592   0 09:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
500      10191 10188  0 48336  5936   0 09:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   10192 10188  0  4867  7300   0 09:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
...
```

So far it works fine, each request contains the configured mod_wsgi.process_group.

However, when file system privileges of the document root are restricted to the daemon user (chmod -R 700), apache will yield an access denied message in the vHost's error log:
"(13)Permission denied: access to / denied"

I wonder why I need to have public read access, when the files are supposed to be accessed by the daemon only?

Note: this happens also when selinux is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Apache needs at least search access (+x) to the directories down to where the WSGI script file is located. This is needed when mapping the URL to the WSGI script file so it can determine if the WSGI script file exists.

Another alternative is to have the WSGI script file in an area outside of the protected directories and then have the WSGI script import a specific Python module from the protected area which contains the actual WSGI application. The WSGI script files could be set up by system admins and not something writable by users.

Comment: Thanks! That was the reason - when apache reads the vHost'S conf, it is not root anymore.

(sorry, cannot up vote - not allowed yet. Still grateful)